# Control over format when using RequestImageFileAsync in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: image-processing, file-upload, blazor-webassembly

Blazor Web assembly has a convenience method that converts an IBrowserFile containing an image into a resized version - which is handy for resizing large images prior to uploading them.

This method takes a format as a string which determines the format of the output file.

Is there anywhere a list of valid formats that this property will accept? Can you specify the compression or bit depth values on the resulting file?

Currently, If I take an existing .jpg file and convert it using a format string of "jpg" the resulting file, although smaller in pixel dimensions is actually about double the size on disk. A 4000x3000 image at about 2.8MB can be "reduced" to a 2000x1500 image that's 7.7MB in size. Which is obviously not helping when the purpose is to reduce upload size. I could easily upload the 2.8MB file and resize it more efficiently on the server.

```
var imageFile = await file.RequestImageFileAsync("jpg", 2000, 2000);
```

This suggests I'm using the method incorrectly - but Microsoft's documentation on this method gives no clues as to what valid "Format" strings might, only stating that it is a string type. I've tried ".jpg", "JPEG", "jpg" - all of which seem to produce the same valid jpg file. What should I be passing here to actually reduce the file size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types

It's actually not "image/jpg" but "image/jpeg". If you specify non-existent format, the fallback (at least for me) seems to be "image/png". That's why you always got a valid image but with the same filesize.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this method uses html types:
[html types](https://www.google.com/search?q=html%20image%20types&oq=html%20image%20types&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j0i22i30l4j0i10i22i30j0i22i30l3.4863j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Try **"image/jpg"**.

Be careful, though, this is a request to the browser, and the browser can send back whatever it wants.  I *believe* this will work fine on all browsers, but you'd better check some of the common culprits (Hi, Opera!) to confirm.

Comment: Sadly, using "image/jpg" has the same effect as using jpeg or jpg. The reduced file is still larger in bytes a than the original.

Comment: I see.  But I'm pretty sure the resulting image matches the dimensions you specified, right?  I've noticed that as well.  I've also noticed that in my test case, calling a .jpg or a .png resulted in the exact same filesize, which leads me to think that the incoming file is uncompressed.  In my case, I was uploading monster images (like 50MB), and HD images came through at 1.7MB, a huge saving-- but a compressed HD image is more like 500KB or so.  If you want to compress at the client with proper settings (.8 quality probably), you might need to do your processing in JS.